# Ошибка "error: assignment to expression with array type"

Tags: c, массивы, разработка-игр, 2d

Хочу нарисовать поле для игры. Создал 2Д масив, и хотел передать кое-какие данные в его ячейки. В итоге выдает ошибку "error: assignment to expression with array type". Как ее можно пофиксить? Спасибо
Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void draw_field() {
    //const int width = 20;
    //const int height = 20;
    char field[20][20];
    field[0] = "####################";
    field[19] = "####################";
    printf("%s\n", field[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
        field[i] = "#                  #";
        printf("%s\n", field[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", field[0]);
}

int main()
{
    const bool gameOver = false;
    draw_field();
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки:

```
main.c: In function ‘draw_field’:
main.c:19:14: error: assignment to expression with array type
     field[0] = "####################";
              ^
main.c:20:15: error: assignment to expression with array type
     field[19] = "####################";
               ^
main.c:23:18: error: assignment to expression with array type
         field[i] = "#                  #";
                  ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Это массивы!

```
strcpy(field[0],"####################");
```

За выделением достаточного места следите сами.

Comment: Спасибо!
А что вы имеете ввиду на счет выделения места?

Comment: @Igor А можно поподробнее, а то мне немного страшно?

Comment: Раз вы написали `char field[20][20];`, то не должны пытаться записать в `field[0]` больше девятнадцаит `#`.

Comment: @Mikhailo: Размер 20. Значит можно записывать 20 `#`. Другое дело, что автору как-будто зачем-то нужна именно *строка* с нулем на конце (не знаю, зачем). А значит нужно еще иметь нулевой терминатор.

Comment: @AnT Я говорил о применении `strcpy`, т.е. о строке.